# minted list of listings and TOC conflict

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, minted, tocbibind

I am using `minted` for source code highlighting.  I want a List of Listings, and I want the List of Listings to itself have an entry in the main Table of Contents. I thought I could do this with `tocbibind` package, and tried to follow the instructions on renewing `\lstlistoflistings` (given on p5 of the [`tocbibind` documentation](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocbibind/tocbibind.pdf)), adapting that code (or so I thought) to work for the `minted` instead of `listings` package.  When I do this (see preamble of MWE below), I get the TOC line, but the List of Listings formatting goes wonky (all entries overlapping on the same line, no row of dots, etc.  Obviously I've left some stuff out of my `\renewcommand` but I'm not sure what.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[nottoc,chapter]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[chapter]{minted} 
\usemintedstyle{default}

% If I comment out the next 3 lines, the list of listings looks 
% normal, but there is no "list of listings" line in the TOC
\renewcommand{\listoflistings}{\begingroup
\tocfile{\listoflistingscaption}{lol}
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoflistings

\chapter{the first chapter}
\section{section one point one}
\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\small, tabsize=2]{r}
x <- runif(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
plot(x, y, axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE, pch=16)
\end{minted}
\caption[short caption for lst1]{Longer caption to be used when listing one appears\label{lst:myLstOne}}
\end{listing}

\chapter{the second chapter}
\section{section two point one}
\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\small, tabsize=2]{r}
a <- runif(5)
b <- rnorm(5)
plot(b, a)
\end{minted}
\caption[short caption for lst2]{Longer caption to be used when listing two appears\label{lst:myLstTwo}}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**
I can get a properly formatted LOL, and a LOL entry in the TOC, if I change the relevant part of the preamble to this:

```
\renewcommand{\listoflistings}{\begingroup
\listof{listing}{\listoflistingscaption}
\tocfile{\listoflistingscaption}{lol}
\endgroup}
```

I got the idea by looking for the definition of `\listoflistings` in the source code of `minted`.  However, then I end up with a *second* (empty) LOL after the first (correct) one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common way to add an unnumbered section or chapter heading to the ToC is:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{<secunit>}{<heading>}
```

This would suggest a redefinition like:

```
\renewcommand{\listoflistings}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listoflistingscaption}%
  \listof{listing}{\listoflistingscaption}%
}
```

However, since `\listof` will issue a chapter heading this implicitly also calls `\cleardoublepage` which means you end up with the wrong page number in the ToC as `\addcontentsline` is expanded before. Placing it after `\listof...` also will fail if the list is more than a page long so the correct redefinition should explicitly call `\cleardoublepage` first itself:

```
\renewcommand{\listoflistings}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listoflistingscaption}%
  \listof{listing}{\listoflistingscaption}%
}
```