# How to let \listoflistings of minted use subsection's subheading and appear in TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, koma-script, minted, tocbasic

I want the `\listoflistings` of minted to appear as a subsection heading. (My `\documentclass` is `scrartcl`.)

Things like `\printbibliography` have a "heading" option, which you can use to define, which heading type it should use. `\printacronyms` (package `acro`) has the same.
With `\KOMAoption{listof}{totocnumbered,leveldown}` I can also move `\listoffigures` from a `section` heading to a `subsection` heading, but as for `\listoflistings` nothing of this works.

Things like [this Stackexchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99628/minted-list-of-listings-and-toc-conflict/99656) did not work  and are also "just" about adding it to the TOC and not - which is my main concern - move it one "heading level" down.

I just want a subheading (`subsection`-like) instead of a heading (`section`).
It would also be nice, if it could appear in the toc.

---

Basically my TOC should be like this:

8. Lists
   8.1. List of figures
   8.2. List of listings
   ...

---

BTW, also asked [in GitHub repo](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/213).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a **KOMA-Script class** like `scrartcl`

```
\addtotoclist[float]{lol}
\renewcommand*\listoflistings{\listoftoc[{\listoflistingscaption}]{lol}}
```

can be used to get the List of Listings (LOL) under control of package `tocbasic`. This package is loaded by the KOMA-Script classes und used for TOC, LOF, LOT, ... automatically. The optional argument of `\addtotoclist` sets `owner=float` for `lol`. So the settings of the KOMA-Script option `listof={...}` will also effect the LOL.

To format the entries for the listings in LOL, you could use

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    level=1,
    indent=1.5em,
    numwidth=2.3em
]{tocline}{listing}
```

or

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\l@listing{\l@figure}
\makeatother
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\KOMAoption{listof}{totocnumbered,leveldown}

\usepackage{minted}
\addtotoclist[float]{lol}
\renewcommand*\listoflistings{\listoftoc[{\listoflistingscaption}]{lol}}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    level=1,
    indent=1.5em,
    numwidth=2.3em
]{default}{listing}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Example Section}
\begin{listing}[hb]
\begin{minted}{java}
System.out.println("Test");
\end{minted}
\caption{Test}
\end{listing}

\section{Lists}
\listoffigures
\listoflistings
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Standard classes** like `article` does not define `\KOMAoptions` and does not load `tocbasic`. But you can load package `tocbasic` manually and use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\addtotoclist[float]{lof}
\renewcommand*\listoffigures{\listoftoc[{\listfigurename}]{lof}}
\addtotoclist[float]{lol}
\renewcommand*\listoflistings{\listoftoc[{\listoflistingscaption}]{lol}}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    level=1,
    indent=1.5em,
    numwidth=2.3em
]{default}{listing}

\doforeachtocfile[float]{%
  \setuptoc{#1}{numbered,leveldown}%
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Example Section}
\begin{listing}[hb]
\begin{minted}{java}
System.out.println("Test");
\end{minted}
\caption{Test}
\end{listing}

\section{Lists}
\listoffigures
\listoflistings

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this does work. If I understand it correctly, it mostly just is stuff to make it behave like `\listoffigures`. If so, this seems like a workaround. So do you think this can/needs to be fixed in the minted package itself?

Comment: Other classes or documents may use other packages (eg. `tocloft`) for the lists ... So maybe it is more like a feature request to get a numbered heading with lower level and a TOC entry for the LOL.

Answer (score 1):

A very basic solution:

- DIY heading by using `\listoftoc*` (which is basically `\@starttoc`)
- LoL format like LoF

[image: list of listings]

Code:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: 1 }
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\KOMAoption{listof}{totocnumbered,leveldown}
\usepackage{minted}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\l@listing{\l@figure}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}{java}
System.out.println("Test");
\end{minted}
\caption{Test}
\end{listing}

\section*{Lists}
\subsection*{List of listings}
\listoftoc*{lol}

\end{document}
```